# How to use the GraalVM Native Image Agent with Quarkus?

Tags: quarkus

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [GraalVM native image agent](https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/native-image/BuildConfiguration/#assisted-configuration-of-native-image-builds) with a Quarkus app running via `mvn quarkus:dev`.

I tried running:

```
mvn quarkus:dev -Djvm.args="-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=native-image-config"
```

However I get the error:

```
ERROR: JDWP unable to get necessary JVMTI capabilities.
```

Any tips?

My version of Java:

```
openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 20.2.0 (build 11.0.8+10-jvmci-20.2-b03, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Comment: Have you tried using OpenJDK as your JDK instead of GraalVM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `mvn quarkus:dev` enables debug with `-Xrunjdwp`, something like `-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:5005,server=y,suspend=n`

Then you stumble upon an issue described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037405/1087978) -- in short JDWP and JVMTI don't seem to work together well.

You can disable debug with passing `-Ddebug=false` and then it works. Something like this:

```
mvn quarkus:dev -Ddebug=false -Djvm.args="-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=native-image-config"
```