# How to run GraalVM native-image tracing agent against Quarkus Maven unit tests to generate a reflection-config.json?

Tags: java, quarkus, graalvm-native-image

I followed the Quarkus project example for Lambda + native-image [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/amazon-lambda) and I was able to get that to work. However now I'm trying to extend it by adding my own code to it which uses some reflection in the library dependencies. I'm trying to run the Quarkus unit tests to alongside the native-image tracing agent to capture the reflection-config.json however I'm unable to do that. I've tried the below approach:

```
mvn clean package -Djvm.args="-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image"
```

Runs the unit test but I don't see anything generated for the tracing agent outputs.

Tried running the following from Oleg's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64450394/how-to-use-the-graalvm-native-image-agent-with-quarkus)

```
mvn quarkus:dev -Ddebug=false -Djvm.args="-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=native-image-config"
```

And didn't see any outputs either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To have the agent operate while running tests, do something like:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
    <!-- Add the rest of your options -->
    <configuration>
    <!-- Add the rest of your configuration --> 
      <argLine>-agentlib:native-image-agent=config-output-dir=META-INF/native-image</argLine>
    </configuration>
```

For the dev-mode, -Djvm.args=... should work just fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it!