# Coldfusion server not starting after reboot, error is "JDWP unable to get necessary JVMTI capabilities". Anyone seen this?

Tags: coldfusion, jvmti, jdwp

After a recent windows system update mandated by our corporate systems team, my local Coldfusion 2018 server quit working.  Since 2018 recently went out of support, I updated to CF 2023.  That wouldn't start either.

If, in a command window, I navigate to the bin location C:\ColdFusion2023\cfusion\bin and type "cfstart"  the error I get is "ERROR: JDWP unable to get necessary JVMTI capabilities".

I had not thought to do this before updating but, when I navigate to the same 2018 bin folder, the same message is given.

I have tried updating my Java to 17.0.18 but the result is the same.

**UPDATE:** This was fixed by removing this section from the jvm.config file in my bin folder (for me, C:\Coldfusion2018\cfusion\bin):

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

I think corporate security update locked down port 5005.  I'll work on getting that opened up.

Full thread is here:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/help-with-cf-server-instances-failing-to-run/m-p/11394467

Comment: Check this other answer to see if that is why you are getting this error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/6037405/1636917.  Also I'm pretty sure Java 17 is not supported.  You will likely want to fall back to Java 11

Comment: Per Charlie Arehart, CF2023 ONLY supports Java 17  https://coldfusion.adobe.com/2021/01/table-of-java-to-cf-versions/

Comment: I googled the error you reported, and landed on this CF forms thread: https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/help-with-cf-server-instances-failing-to-run/m-p/11394467. Is it that?

Comment: @AdamCameron  Yes!  Thank you!  I'll update my post with that fix.

Comment: I'd make it an answer so you can accept it and tick the question off

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: This was fixed by removing this section from the jvm.config file in my bin folder (for me, C:\Coldfusion2018\cfusion\bin):

-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005

Full thread is here:

https://community.adobe.com/t5/coldfusion-discussions/help-with-cf-server-instances-failing-to-run/m-p/11394467